# Mailchimp API returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to implement an API to read if user exists as a member in my mailchimp account and if it is not there then add this member to the list.
I am using @marketing/mailchimp_marketing library as a reference (https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-node).
The issue: mailchimp is returning 'undefined'. Maybe I am missing something in the code and I am afraid setConfig is not been read (not sure). I really appreciate your support. This is the code used:

---

```
const md5 = require('md5');
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: 'my-api-key',
  server: 'my-server',
});

const listId = '#listcode';

async function checkstatus(subscriber) { //subscriber is an object received from another js file through 
                                         //checkstatus function.
  console.log(subscriber); // returns the object ok
  const status_id = 'subscribed';

  for (let i = 0; i < subscriber.length - 24; i++) {
    const no_email = subscriber[i].email.toLowerCase();
    const subscriberHash = md5(no_email);
    const FNAME_Name = subscriber[i].nome;
    const LNAME_Name = subscriber[i].sobrenome;

    try {
      const response = await mailchimp.lists.getListMember(
        listId,
        subscriberHash
      );
      console.log(`${response.status}`); // returns 'undefined'
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.status); // returns 'undefined'
      console.log('nao cadastrado');
      addmember(no_email, FNAME_Name, LNAME_Name, status_id);
    }
  }
  alert('Done');
}

export { checkstatus };

async function addmember(no_email, FNAME_Name, LNAME_Name, status_id) {
  try {
    const run = async () => {
      const additional = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
        email_address: no_email,
        status: status_id,
        merge_fields: {
          FNAME: FNAME_Name,
          LNAME: LNAME_Name,
        },
      });
      console.log(
        `Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${additional.id}.`
      );
    };
    run();
  } catch (e) {
    //console.error(e.status);
    console.log(e.status);
  }
  return;
}
```